Does the story continue after Mephisto captures Doctor Strange in Defenders: The Best Defense?
After reading through the "Best Defense" Defenders arc (2018), including its conclusion in Defenders: The Best Defense, I noticed the story ends on a cliffhanger. Doctor Strange's astral projection is captured by Mephisto, though Strange cryptically mentions he has a plan.

I followed up by reading Doctor Strange (Vol. 5) #10 (2019), which was referenced in the final pages of Defenders: The Best Defense. However, this issue seems to be telling a completely different story with no connection to the Best Defense arc.

Does this plot thread with Mephisto capturing Strange continue or get referenced in any other comic series or issues? If so, which series or issues cover it?

According to the Marvel Database page for that issue, the Dr. Strange who appeared there is not the 616 version, but one from an alternate reality with only three appearances, that issue being the most recent of them.
